# functions that are $\mathcal{K}$-infinity continuous not Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

We call a function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ $\mathcal{K}$-infinity continuous if $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq \omega(|x_1 - x_2|)$, with $\omega: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ obeying $\omega$ is strictly increasing, $\omega(0) = 0$, and $\lim_{s \rightarrow +\infty}\omega(s) = +\infty$.

Is there a function on an interval $\mathcal{K}$-infinity continuous but not Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Is your question about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity ?

Comment: It is a stronger version of modulus of continuity, here $\omega$ is required to be strictly increasing and infinity at infinity. @Martin R

Comment: But the examples from Wikipedia should still work, shouldn't they? Such as $\omega(t) = t^\alpha$ which describes Hölder-continuity (and that does not imply Lipschitz continuity).